# Removing by ID from a .json file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am having a hard time removing a record in my .json file by `id`.
So my original JSON looks like this:

```
[["{\"id\":1474753066818,\"name\":\"dd\",\"brand\":\"dd\",\"price\":\"12\"}"],["{\"id\":1474753069035,\"name\":\"dd3\",\"brand\":\"dd\",\"price\":\"12\"}"]]
```

And this is my php:

```
 <?php
    $string = file_get_contents("products.json");
    //var_dump($string);
    $input = json_decode($string, true);
    $output = array();
  //here starts the problem
    foreach($input as $element) { 
        if($_GET['data'] != $element[0]["id"]){ //add in array if id doesn't match
           $output[] = $element;
        }
    }
    $final =  json_encode($output);
    $f = @fopen("products.json", "r+");
    if ($f !== false) {
        ftruncate($f, 0);
        fclose($f);
    }
    file_put_contents("products.json", $final);
    >
```

Basically my problem starts in the `foreach` where I am iterating through something that looks like this :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(58) "{"id":1474753066818,"name":"dd","brand":"dd","price":"12"}" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(59) "{"id":1474753069035,"name":"dd3","brand":"dd","price":"12"}" } }
```

Obviously here I am not able to access the `id` like I am trying to do in the foreach, because the whole thing is a string.

I have no idea how can I turn this string to an array, compare the id's and then encode it back to my original json format shown at the begining of this post.

Please help!

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Your products.json file is a little strange, see below:

```
[  
  [  
    "{\"id\":1474753066818,\"name\":\"dd\",\"brand\":\"dd\",\"price\":\"12\"}"
  ],
  [  
    "{\"id\":1474753069035,\"name\":\"dd3\",\"brand\":\"dd\",\"price\":\"12\"}"
  ]
]
```

Your products.json contains *an array of arrays with 1 element whose value is a json encoded string*. It looks like you will have to call `json_decode` again on the string contents to get what you're after.

```
foreach($input as $element) { 
   $product = json_decode($element[0]);
   if($_GET['data'] != $product["id"]){ 
      //add in array if id doesn't match
      $output[] = $product ;
   }
}
```

It's also important to note that the rest of your code:

```
$final =  json_encode($output);
$f = @fopen("products.json", "r+");
if ($f !== false) {
    ftruncate($f, 0);
    fclose($f);
}
file_put_contents("products.json", $final);
```

Will not ending up saving the products.json in the same way that you are currently reading it. With the code I provided above it will probably end up looking like this:

```
[  
   {"id":1474753066818,"name":"dd","brand":"dd","price":"12"},
   {"id":1474753069035,"name":"dd3","brand":"dd","price":"12"}
]
```